# Update using subquery in plsql block

Tags: sql, oracle

If comm is null, I need to update the `comm` value to `salary`, which is `1100`, but it is not getting updated.

My data is:

```
sal        comm    
9000    800
2975    800
3000    800
1100    
3000    800
```

My code is:

```
declare
  cursor c3 is select sal,comm,ename from emp where deptno=20
  for update of comm;
begin
  for c in c3
  loop
    if c.comm is null
    then
      update emp set comm=(select c.sal from emp e where e.comm=c.comm )
      where current of c3;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Please give me opinion on this.

Comment: s it is not updating any row, but not getting any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
update emp set comm=(select c.sal from emp e where e.comm=c.comm )
```

... will not work. You know `c.comm` is null, so you're trying to find a record on `emp` with a matching value, and you can't use an equality test for `null`. This also won't work if there is more than one record where `comm` is `null` - in that case, which of the possible `sal` values would it use?

You don't need to query `emp` again at all; the `select` is pointless, even if it worked, since you can get the data from the row you're updating:

```
update emp set comm = sal
where current of c3;
```

You could also remove the `if` test by changing your cursor to only look for `null` values:

```
cursor c3 is select sal,comm,ename
  from emp
  where deptno=20
  and comm is null
  for update of comm;
```

But as other answers have already pointed out, you don't need to do this in PL/SQL at all, a simple SQL `update` would suffice.

Comment: it worked :) .. but how can i update Multiple null with simple sql update, as you had mention in the above answer.

Comment: @user2686661 - exactly how the other two answers said to do it. Why do you think that won't work?

Comment: i need to update a Column  having many null values in comm with Corresponding salary values..but if i go by this--update Employee
set com = sal
where com is null.-- then all comm values will be update to a single sal value.. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @user2686661 - you are wrong. Which `sal` value would it use? Try it on a small table. Actually, here's a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4053e/1).

Comment: Sorry was in bit confusion , Thank you  very much. s we can also do in sql. It helped a ton.:)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
update Employee
set com = sal
where com is null
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple update statement.

`UPDATE YourTable SET comm = sal WHERE comm IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but if there are more comm with null value and i need to update those null value with Corresponding  salary , then what should i do

Comment: @user2686661 - that's what this will do; it will set each null `comm` to the `sal` from the same row.